# Returning an html file from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to return an HTML file say `somename.htm` from the controller`s action method in MVC. How can i do this?

**EDIT**

I have lots of html template ( small websites ) which i want to show user when user select anyone of them on client side.So instead of making all these template as a `view` i saved it as a html file on the server.

Comment: `return Content(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("<file path>"));`

Comment: The filename, the file itself in its entiriy or a section the markup?

Comment: Do you want the browser to download or display that file? For display simply return the View() and keep ActionResult as the return type of your Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult downloadFile()
{
    var path = "somename.htm";

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);            

    FileContentResult file = File(fileBytes, "text/html");

    return file;
}
```

Comment: What ist the StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); line for?

Comment: @MatthiasS. its the the location of the file which we want to server, usually you wound want to use something like `Server.MapPath(" ")`